# I am trying to get a call to action button on the front screen of my mobile preview, without changing the web layout

Tags: css

I am currently using Zoho to edit a website. Unfortunately, the webpage isn't loading correctly on mobile and the call to action button (which is a phone number)isn't loading as the first point of contact of the webpage on mobile. Zoho gives you the option to edit the CSS builder.  Basically the header is stretched and the call to action button won't stay up top.

We have already tried...

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .zpbutton {
    font-size: 21px
  }
}
```

Comment: You are required to provide a  [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You class might be getting overwritten by another class with a longer name.

Please try this :

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

.zpbutton {
    font-size: 21px !important;
}

}
```